# List Comprehension - Double Loop or Not?

Tags: python

I am having the following issue:

```
# Neither this

trial1 = [[x for x in 10000 // 5**i] for i in range(1, 10)]

# nor this

trial2 = [x for i in range(1, 10) for x in 10000 // 5**i]

# work.
```

They both return: "int" object is not iterable, which is somehow confusing to me. Since `i` is an array `(1,2,3,...,9)` so must be the `10000 // 5**i` formula. So which is the integer `i` can't iterate over?. I want `trial` to be a list containing all these values.

How is this so different?

```
trial = []
for i in range(1, k):
    trial.append(10000 // 5**i)
```

How does one go about formulating the list comprehension statement?

Comment: There's no double loop in your working example, so why the nested comprehension?

Comment: The for x in clauses try to iterate over an integer.  Your final code has an n in it.  Where did that get set?

Comment: Neither `i` is an array nor `10000 // 5**i`. `i` is an integer between 1 and 10. (First loop i=1, second loop i=2, ...). So `10000 // 5**i` is just an integer and you can not iterate integers.

Comment: Thanks all. I get it now. I'll upvote all 3 and just select one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comprehension equivalent of your working `for` loop would be:

```
[10000 // 5**i for i in range(1, 10)]
```

There are no double loops in that example, so there shouldn't be in the comprehension either.

Regarding your second question; `i` is *not* a list with values `(0, 1, ... , 9)` but it is a single integer out of that list.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of

```
trial = []
for i in range(1, k):
    trial.append(n // 5**i)
```

is simply

```
trial = [10000 // 5**i for i in range(1, k)]
```

since you are simply calculating `10000 // 5**i` for ever `i` in `range(1, k)`

Answer (score 1):

`for x in 10000 // 34**i` or anything like that means *iterating through a number*, which doesn't make sense and results in an error.

You seem to be trying to append numbers to a list, which is easy:

```
trial = [10000 // 5**i for i in range(1, 5)]
```

Here you're basically saying:

1. Create a list (`[...]`)
2. That consists of values, each of them is equal to `10000//5**i`
3. Where `i` is every number from `range(1, 5)`